# How to detect undisturbed forest plot in Mudumalai National Park?

Tags: remote-sensing, forest-ecology

I am looking for undisturbed forest plot (without logging for at least 50 years) in Mudumalai National Park (India) or around it. How to detect it using GIS or remote sensing?

Comment: What GIS software do you have available to you?  Do you have data already, if so, what format? I'm unsure if you're looking for data or just a way to interpret your data.

Comment: I have ArcMap, Arc Globe and ArcCatalog however I do not have maps. First I do not know where to download them and what steps to use in order to detect such plot.

Comment: Classifying forest cover is a fairly simple task using spectral remote sensing. However, determining the age of last harvest is more tricky unless you have access to LiDAR data.